# App to replace some of my acronyms

Tags: ios, applications

I saw a video at some point recent.  In the video, the guy had an app that would replace certain phrases with other phrases.

Example:

I type "afaik" and it replaces it with "as far as I know".

My iPod is a gen2 running iOS v4.x and jailbroken.

Comment: You clearly aren't talking about a second generation iPod. Do you mean a second generation iPad, or a second generation iPod Touch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most prominent app would by [TextExpander](http://www.smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/), available for Mac OS and iOS. Another alternative would be [Typinator](http://www.ergonis.com/products/typinator/) only Mac OS.

Another option (on iOS 5) would be shortcuts (Settings -> General -> Keyboard). You can add shortcuts and replacements as in your example. This is probably the best solutions as it is free and works in all apps. (TextExpander works only in some, that explicitly support it.)

Comment: It's too bad the keyboard shortcuts prefs pane in Mac OSX doesn't have this feature. If it did, it would be nice if it synced with the iOS 5 capability through iCloud.

Comment: TextExpander works in all OSX apps and some iOS app (for unsupported iOS apps you'll just have to copy and paste) and syncs between iOS and Mac OS.